# Extracting Facebook profile picture

Tags: javascript, facebook, jsp, profile, image

I am building a metro application in Windows 8 and I want that it will syncronize with Facebook.
I would like to present the picture in my jsp file. The jsp file will be presented after the user will click on the facebook notification he recieved.

When I asked only the name of the user I succeeded but when I ask the profile picture I face on obstacles.

I created a XMLHTTPRequest for Facebook and Facebook sends me as a response "JFIF".

```
function getFacebookPicture(facebookUser) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var str = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookUser.id + "/picture";
    request.open("GET", str, false);
    request.send();
    var response = request.responseText;
    return response;
}//getPic()
```

response = "JFIF".

I got it and send the notification.

```
 function sendNotification2() {

    var uid = facebookUser.id;
    var picture = getFacebookPicture(facebookUser);


    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var appID = "XXXXXX"; // the app id
    var appSecret = "YYYYYYYY"; // the app secret 
    var notificationContent = "YO yo yo"; // the message on the notification.
    var str = "https://graph.facebook.com/" +
        uid + "/notifications?access_token=" +
        appID + "|" + appSecret + "&href=?name=" + facebookUser.name +"?picture="+ picture + "&template=" +notificationContent + "&method=POST&format=json";

    request.open("GET", str, false);
    request.send();
    var response = request.responseText;
}
```

The error I got is

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}
```

I added to my app the permissions : read_friendlists,manage_notifications,publish_stream,offline_access,user_photos when I log in.

So how can I get the picture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you query this URL -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture
```

You don't get the "path" to the image. You get the image itself. I'm not sure how exactly you are implementing the profile pictures, but I do know that on a regular webpage, one would simply place that URL in the `src` of an `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture" width="50" >
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFacebookPicture(facebookUser) {
    return "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookUser.id + "/picture";
}//getPic()
```

Start reading [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) to find out how to get an access token.